# Saving ConnectionString in App.config

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use the following method to save connection strings in the `app.config` at run time on a per user basis:

```
public void saveConnectionString(string serverName, string conn)
{
    Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoamingAndLocal);
    var connectionString = config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings[serverName];
    config.ConnectionStrings.SectionInformation.AllowExeDefinition = ConfigurationAllowExeDefinition.MachineToLocalUser;
    if (connectionString == null)
    {
        config.ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings.Add(new ConnectionStringSettings
        {
            Name = serverName,
            ConnectionString = conn,
            ProviderName = "System.Data.SqlClient"
        });

        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    }
    else
    {
        connectionString.ConnectionString = conn;
    }
}
```

I'm getting an exception:

*ConfigurationSection properties cannot be edited when locked.*

when I try to get the `ConfigurationAllowExeDefinition`. Is there a way round this of do I need to create my own section?

Comment: Please post the exception and error, we aren't mind readers....

Comment: Is it possible at all to change config at runtime? That would require at least reboot of web app? No?

Comment: I've added the exception message and its a winform app not a web app.

Comment: @JerrySwitalski: Its an app.config, not a web.config so I don't think there is a web app involved.

Comment: @Chris what an embarrassment, I was pretty sure I saw asp.net tag somewhere here...

Answer (score 0):

Try with  below code after the code **config.Save**  :-

ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings");

Comment: The exception occurs before it reaches the save.

Comment: Hope this will work for you try this. config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal)
instead of (ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);

Comment: This still won't work as the exception is happening at the line:config.ConnectionStrings.SectionInformation.AllowExeDefinition = ConfigurationAllowExeDefinition.MachineToLocalUser; and it never gets to the save part

Answer (score 0):

```
We cant add to ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings using ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings.Add(connectionStringSettings) -- This fails.
But we can add to the configuration section and refresh the ConfigurationManager.

public static void AddConnectionStringSettings(
       System.Configuration.Configuration config,
       System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings conStringSettings)

{   
   ConnectionStringsSection connectionStringsSection = config.ConnectionStrings; 
  connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings.Add(conStringSettings);  
  config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Minimal); 
  ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("connectionStrings"); 
}
```

Comment: I still get the section is locked exception when I use your method